# How to connect C# Visual Studio 2013 to php myadmin database

Tags: visual-studio, phpmyadmin

I need a connector for C# Visual Studio to php myadmin database. I've searched about it but every time I get the connector of MYSQL. I don't need a MYSQL connector for C# VS. I need a connector for php myadmin databse. Help me please.....

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the `RDBMS` that PHP MyAdmin works with. PHP MyAdmin is **NOT** a database system, it is a user interface to interact with a MySQL database.

Here is a link to an article explaining exactly how to connect a `C#` application to a MySQL database: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL